# How to bold a string in groovy?

Tags: groovy, fonts, format, jenkins-groovy, bold

Is it possible to change the font in Groovy Console Output? I want to bold certain string in my groovy. Tried this 6 codes it wont work.

```
echo "*hello* world!"
echo "<b>hello</b> world!"
echo "<strong>hello</strong> world!"
println("*hello* world!")
println("<b>hello</b> world!")
println("<strong>hello</strong> world!")
```

Comment: https://plugins.jenkins.io/ansicolor/